# Filter table rows by link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, filtering

I searched around and couldn't find an exact solution to my problem, so here goes. I'm trying to filter the rows of a table by hiding unmatched rows by link click.

```
<a class="all">All: 314</a>
<a class="processing">Processing: 16</a>
<a class="completed">Completed: 12</a>
<a class="action">Action Required: 34</a>
<a class="errors">Errors: 6</a>
```

Here's an abbreviated version of the table:

```
<table id="batch">
<tr class="processing">Processing</tr>
<tr class="completed">Completed</tr>
<tr class="action">Action Required</tr>
<tr class="errors">Error</tr>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using (tbody to avoid filtering the thead and some hidden rows):

```
$("a.processing").click(function(){
    $("table#batch tbody tr:not(.processing)").fadeOut();
});

$("a.completed").click(function(){
    $("table#batch tbody tr:not(.completed)").fadeOut();
});

$("a.action").click(function(){
    $("table#batch tbody tr:not(.actionrequired)").fadeOut();
});

$("a.error").click(function(){
    $("table#batch tbody tr:not(.error)").fadeOut();
});
```

The problem is that once you've filtered by one class, filtering again by another becomes impossible because all of the values except for the ones previously filtered are hidden. This happens with both `.fadeOut();` and `.hide();`

I know there's a much simpler, less hacky way of accomplishing this, I just can't seem to get my head around it or get it to let me filter successively.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at https://datatables.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).attr('class')` to select `tr` with same class as clicked `a` element

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('#batch tr').hide();
  $('tr.' + $(this).attr('class') + '').show();
  if ($(this).attr('class') == 'all') $('table tr').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="all">All: 314</a>
<a class="processing">Processing: 16</a>
<a class="completed">Completed: 12</a>
<a class="action">Action Required: 34</a>
<a class="errors">Errors: 6</a>
<br>
<table id="batch">
  <tr class="processing"> <td>Processing</td></tr>
  <tr class="processing"> <td>Processing</td></tr>
  <tr class="processing"> <td>Processing</td></tr>
  <tr class="completed"> <td>Completed</td></tr>
  <tr class="completed"> <td>Completed</td></tr>
  <tr class="action"> <td>Action Required</td></tr>
  <tr class="errors"> <td>Error</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does work, but only for the first table row with a matching class- I need to display all matching table rows.

Comment: This only displays one matching table row. My table has several rows for each category (16 processing, 12 completed, etc.) and this only displays the first one on click.

Comment: One more quick question- how would you integrate toggling an active class on the links? I tried doing this but it broke the filtering functionality.